# Regex to find unlimited quantity of alphanumeric characters but only one '=' between two characters

Tags: regex

I have a string similar to "&jaks1123kanasd=aks91341sj13jasd&" and want to create a regex that checks that this string contains alphanumeric characters between two '&' (excluding the second '&' from the match) and contains exactly one occurrence of the '=' character. I currently have:

`&[a-z0-9_={1}]+(?=&)`

However, this allows for multiple '=' character. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `&\w+=\w+&` add groups where you want

Comment: This looks a lot like a URL query string, am I right? If so then could you use a URL parsing utility from whatever language you're using?

Comment: Your regexp also allows `{}` characters. `{1}` doesn't have any special meaning inside square brackets, it's just a list of characters to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
(&[a-z0-9_]+=[a-z0-9_]+)&
```

or

```
(&\w+=\w+)&
```

When you use square brackets, you are specifying a list of characters that can occur in that position, the plus indicates there should be one or more. So

```
[a-z0-9_={1}]+
```

means that there should be one or more of the characters listed, including the braces. The curly braces used to specify length cannot be used inside the square brackets.